# What's the equivalent of a python @classmethod or @staticmethod in Scala?

Tags: python, scala

This is useful when I don't want to use implicits but would like to have a function to convert from (e.g.) `Int` to `MyClass`.

Comment: can you give an example of how you would like to use them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scala, an `object` is used to define static methods.  What you are describing sounds like you want this:

```
class MyClass(n: Int)

object MyClass {
  def apply(n: Int) = new MyClass(n)
}
```

So that you can do either of these:

```
scala> val a = MyClass.apply(3)
a: MyClass = MyClass@70d1c9b5

scala> val b = MyClass(3)       // works allowed because method is called "apply"
b: MyClass = MyClass@1b4b2db7
```

I would call this a "factory method".

Answer (score 2):

You can put a method into the companion object to call it in a static way from Scala (i.e. without an object instance):

```
// Scala
class A
object A {
  def staticMethod = println("Foo!")
}
A.staticMethod // prints "Foo!"
```

note that the Scala compiler actually creates a new synthetic class called `A$` for the singleton `object A`, so the line `A.staticMethod` calls the method on a single instance of `A$` which exists at runtime.

Noteworthy: The Scala compiler also creates a static method `staticMethod` in `A` on the bytecode level which forwards the call to `A$.staticMethod` - in case you're mixing Java and Scala code in your project, this means that you will also be able to call this static method from Java like this:

```
// Java
A.staticMethod(); // works
```

However, if you declare the method with the same name in the companion class `A`, while everything still works in the same way in Scala, the static forwarder method in `A` will **not** be generated, and you will not be able to call `staticMethod` from Java:

```
// Scala
class A {
  def staticMethod = println("I'm doing something else.")
}
object A { // no companion class
  def staticMethod = println("Foo!")
}
A.staticMethod // prints "Foo!"

// Java
A.staticMethod(); // won't work
```